# Typescript, mat chip lost inside a ckeditor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ckeditor, chips

I need to put the chips INSIDE a ckeditor. I already have configurated the mat chips module and the ckeditor module and add the chips but out pf the ckeditor.
just like this...

[What i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd0sR.jpg)

[What i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVG80.jpg)

I didn't find anything about it